# How to efficiently update a row on Hibernate by NaturalId?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to write a method in my repository that receives an entity with a natural id, so what i'm actually doing is to retrieve the entity using the bySimpleNaturalId() method from the Session class, and then updating its fields using the setter methods:

```
SomeEntity db = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class)
            .bySimpleNaturalId(SomeEntity.class)
            .load(entity.getNaturalId());
db.setField1(entity.getField1());
...
```

However, i've noticed that this approach triggers a select query that retrieves all entity fields from the database, and then updates the same field. So my question is, how to avoid the select query, since i don't need those field values because i'm only using the entity to update some of its values.

Thank you very much

Comment: I don't know if there is a hibernate configuration that will give you what you want (I suspect there is not, simply due to the design around managed entities, dirty checking, etc.). However, if you need a different approach, you certainly can accomplish the update using a native query, which would not require any select if you don't want it. If you use native queries, be aware of the issues around flushing (you need to tell hibernate which tables are being changed or queried by the native query). Hibernate provides perfectly good support for native queries.

Comment: "Updating entity objects in the database using an UPDATE query may be slightly more efficient than retrieving entity objects and then updating them, but it should be used cautiously because bypassing the EntityManager may break its synchronization with the database. For example, the EntityManager may not be aware that a cached entity object in its persistence context has been modified by an UPDATE query. Therefore, it is a good practice to use a separate EntityManager for UPDATE queries."

Following link may help you. https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/update